# Line integral and attraction of a material point by a material curve in R^3

Tags: line-integrals

According to Newton's law of universal gravitation, a material point $P$ with mass $m$ attracts a material point $P_0$ with mass $m_0$ with a force directed from $P_0$ towards $P$, of size $k\cfrac{mm_0}{r^2}$ (further for simplicity k=1).

Note that when the point $P_0$ (located at the point $(0, 0, 0)$) of mass $m_0$,
is attracted by the point $P_i$ (located in the point $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$) of mass $m_i$,
is the force acting between them we express as
$$\dfrac{m_om_i}{r_i^2}(x_i,y_i,z_i),$$
where $r_i=\sqrt{(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2)}$.

In the situation where the point $P_0$ is attracted by points $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n$ with masses $m_1, m_2,\ldots,m_n$ and the attracting mass has a continuous distribution on the curve $\sigma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3, \sigma(t)=(\sigma_1(t),\sigma_2(t),\sigma_3(t))$, the curve is divided into small segments by points $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b$. Then we write the force of attraction as the sum of the vectors

$$\sum_i \dfrac{m_0m_i}{r_i(\sigma(t_i))}(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i)).$$

How to express $m_i$ - the mass of a section from $t_{i-1}$ to $t_i$ using a line integral and the whole as a Rieman sum of a certain integer?

Comment: It is more typically to assume the curve has some parameterization $\gamma: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and a scalar density parameterized along the curve $\rho: [a,b]\to (0,\infty)$ then an infinitesimal force contribution is $\frac{m_o \rho r \mathrm{d}s}{\|r\|^3}$

Comment: I need to understand it in my notation :/

Comment: I think all you need is do define a mass density function along the curve so that $m_i = \rho(t_i)~\mathrm{d}\sigma$ and you have your Riemann sum. Be careful with your definition of graviational force in vector form. You should have $F = \frac{m_o m_i}{r_i^3}(x_i,y_i,z_i)$.

Comment: thanks, I will change $r_i^2$ to $r_i^3$. Can we assume that:     $$m_i=\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}f(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i))\sqrt{\sigma_1'(t_i)^2+\sigma_2'(t_i)^2+\sigma_3'(t_i)^2}\,dt?$$

Comment: That looks correct. Approximating that integral into something times $\Delta t$ should give you your Riemann sum for the force.

Comment: Should I also have $$\sum_i \dfrac{m_0m_i}{r_i(\sigma(t_i))^3}(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i)).$$ instead of $$\sum_i \dfrac{m_0m_i}{r_i(\sigma(t_i))}(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i))?$$

Comment: @whpowell96 $$F=\sum_i \dfrac{m_0\cdot \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}f(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i))\sqrt{\sigma_1'(t_i)^2+\sigma_2'(t_i)^2+\sigma_3'(t_i)^2}dt}{r_i(\sigma(t_i))}(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i)).$$
do you know what i need to do more?